# Open 3D Mesh/Point Cloud texture mapping

Tags: python, point-clouds, texture-mapping, render-to-texture, open3d

I've been working on converting 2d png image to 3d obj/GLTF using python Open3D I've created Point clouds using depth map (RGBD Image) now I'm stuck applying texture to my 3d Model and also voxel downsampling is not working I've been using original point clouds obtained from RGBD image.

## Downsampling

```
downpcd = pcd.voxel_down_sample(voxel_size=0.05)
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([downpcd])
```

## Mesh Regeneration

```
alpha = 0.0015
mesh = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_from_point_cloud_alpha_shape(updatedPcd,alpha)
mesh.compute_vertex_normals()
```

I don't know exact syntax to apply texture didn't find anything on Open3D official website please help been stuck for too long